# Problem 3-26 in "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak. How to solve this problem using Fubini's theorem effectively?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, fubini-tonelli-theorems

The following problem is Problem 3-26 in "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.
I could solve this problem directly from the definition of "integrable" and "Jordan-measurable".
But this problem is after the section whose title is "FUBINI'S THEOREM".
How to solve this problem using Fubini's theorem effectively?

> Problem 3-26.
> Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be integrable and non-negative and let $A_f=\{(x,y):a\leq x\leq b\text{ and }0\leq y\leq f(x)\}$. Show that $A_f$ is Jordan-measurable and has area $\int_a^b f$.

My attempt:

Since $f$ is integrable, $B=\{x:f\text{ is not continuous at }x\}$ is a set of measure $0$ by Theorem 3-8.
Let $c$ be a positive real number such that $f(x)\leq c$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.
Then by Fubini's theorem, $$\int_{A_f} 1=\int_{[a,b]\times [0,c]} 1\cdot\chi_{A_f}=\int_{[a,b]\times [0,c]}\chi_{A_f}\\=\int_{[a,b]}\left(\mathbf{U}\int_{[0,c]}\chi_{A_f}(x,y)\,dy\right)\,dx=\int_{[a,b]}\left(\mathbf{L}\int_{[0,c]}\chi_{A_f}(x,y)\,dy\right)\,dx.$$

Comment: Hint: $\int_{[a,b]}\int_{[0,c]}\chi_{A_f}(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{[a,b]}\int_{[0,f(x)]}\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: @Lorago $\int_{[0,c]}\chi_{A_f}(x,y)\,dy=\int_{[0,f(x)]}\chi_{A_f}(x,y)\,dy+\int_{[f(x),c]}\chi_{A_f}(x,y)\,dy=\int_{[0,f(x)]}1\,dy+\int_{[f(x),c]}0\,dy=\int_{[0,f(x)]}1\,dy=f(x)$. Thank you very much for your answer!